# CSS não responde abaixo do Header

Tags: html5, css3

Desculpe se é uma pergunta boba, porém de fato não estou conseguindo ver o problema ou não tive essa vivência bem, pois sou iniciante. Estou desenvolvendo através do Dreamweaver CC e meu CSS tem funcionado perfeitamente lá, porém quando passo para os navegadores, somente o Header aparece com a formatação d cores e tamanho corretos. As outras seções não aparecem formatadas.

```css
#topo {
  background-color: #C4EF25;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

;
#menu {
  background-color: #174BF3;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width:
}

;
#corpo {
  background-color: #cccccc;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  clear: both;
  /* nao permite outro obj flutuar sob a seção corpo */
}

;
#rodape {
  background-color: #FDFC0D;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

;
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Documento sem título</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS\estilo.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header id="topo">
    <center> DOE AGORA </center>
  </header>
  <nav id="menu">
    <center>QUEM SOMOS | NOSSA HISTÓRIA | CONTATO</center>
  </nav>
  <section id="corpo">
    <p>ESTE É O CORPO</p>
  </section>
  <footer id="rodape"> MAPA DO SITE </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Não rasure as publicações.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remova os `;` ao final de suas classes.

```css
#topo {
  background-color: #C4EF25;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#menu {
  background-color: #174BF3;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width:
}

#corpo {
  background-color: #cccccc;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  clear: both;
  /* nao permite outro obj flutuar sob a seção corpo */
}

#rodape {
  background-color: #FDFC0D;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Documento sem título</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS\estilo.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header id="topo">
    <center> DOE AGORA </center>
  </header>
  <nav id="menu">
    <center>QUEM SOMOS | NOSSA HISTÓRIA | CONTATO</center>
  </nav>
  <section id="corpo">
    <p>ESTE É O CORPO</p>
  </section>
  <footer id="rodape"> MAPA DO SITE </footer>
</body>
```